# Java scanner and count not working

Tags: java, oop

I want the code to 'count' the number of hours entered however it is not working. Is the 'hours++' correct?
Can someone please help me. Thanks.

```
    Service temp = null;

    if (temp == null) {
        System.out.printf("Error!");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = sc.nextDouble();
        boolean recordHours = temp.recordHours(hoursWorked);
        sc.nextLine();

        if (recordHours == true) {
            System.out.printf("Worked hours recorded for " + "\"" + a + "\"");
        }
        else
            System.out.printf("Error!");
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public boolean recordHours(double hours) {
    if (hours <= 0) 
        return false;
    else {
        hours++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `temp` is `null`. So, `else` block will never be executed

Comment: temp is null always. check your code

Comment: Can you paste fragment of code where you initialize `sc`?

Answer (score 6):

Java is a pass by value language. Changing `hours` inside `recordHours` only changes a local variable, and not the original variable passed to the method.